# Even though i added generated fatjar to my project ,my project generating issues when gradle building from command line , how to resolve this?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, uberjar

I have one spring boot project with gradle as build tool , i created fat jar for that project , i am adding this fat jar to other project , in the build.gradle as below

```
compile(group: 'com.rules.base', name: 'rules-base', version: '2.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
```

but when a building this project after adding the farjar from terminal , using

```
gradle clean build
```

compilation issue coming , complaining that spring classes not present , one example issue is

```
error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
```

even though i did not the add the spring boot dependencies for the second project explicitly in build.gradle , i added the fat jar , that fat jar contains all the spring boot dependencies , then why `gradle clean build` is giving issue like that ?

can anyone please help me

Comment: Because a Spring Boot jar isn't a regular jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum , i included all the jars , including this spring boot jar also to the uber jar , then still why giving errors like this ?

Comment: That isn't what you are stating in your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum uber jar means , it contains the project classes and the dependencies of that project also

Comment: Trust me I known what it is... I also quite well known that a Spring Boot jar isn't a regular jar (check the documentation and the explanation to the question I marked this as duplicate with!).